# Firestore references create a "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

I'm using Firebase's Firestore inside a Vue JS app:

```
"firebase": "^5.8.0",
"vue-firestore": "^0.3.16",
```

When I try fetching a document which has a field referencing another document (reference type in Firestore), I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
```

Whenever I change the type of that field in the document to a string, it seems to work fine.

I understand this is because of something in the Firestore JS SDK that is trying to serialize the document (and a bunch of metadata coming with the document) to JSON and there is a circular reference somewhere?

In my data's structure and fields I do not have a circular reference. It's simply one field that is referencing another document, and the referenced document has no more references to any other document.

My code for fetching the data is:

```
methods: {
      getContent() {
        const db = this.$firebase.firestore();
        db
          .collection('places')
          .doc(this.$route.params.placeKey)
          .orderBy('name')
          .get()
          .then(snap => {
            this.places = []

            snap.forEach(doc => {
              this.places.push(doc.data())
            })
          })
      }
```

So my questions are:

1) First of all, am I doing something incorrectly in my code? Even if there was no error being raised, would Firestore's JS SDK resolve the reference for me? Or would I have to call the reference and resolve it myself to get the referenced document's data?
2) What's the best practice with Firestore when you have documents you can be referenced? Should you use references? When? When would you denormalize?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the "code is doing something incorrect": it's a problem with the code's generation of a cyclic object-graph. Consider: `x = {}; x.y = x; JSON.stringify(x)` for a trivial way to reproduce the issue. Such *a cyclic-graph cannot be serialized with `JSON.stringify`* (there are other methods of serialization cyclic-graphs, notably: refs and truncation; neither of which apply to `JSON.stringify`). Look at the object-graph at the call site of the error: why is it cyclic?

Comment: "In my data's structure and fields I do not have a circular reference." See the error message above. Don't doubt the exception messages. It's correct. Find out why (which might be unexpected).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer to your second question about storing References: actually, **at the time of writing this answer**, there is no *real* advantage of storing References (i.e. path elements) as [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) type instead of storing them as String.

Please watch this official video from Firebase https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elg2zDVIcLo&t=274s which contains detailed explanations (starting at 4:34).

Comment: why is creating a link instead of copies that are likely to be outdated not considered a real advantage? Also, VueFire supports automatic resolving of references which is quite handy.

Comment: @Boern "why is creating a link instead of copies that are likely to be outdated not considered a real advantage" => because (at the time of writing) it is not a link, it it just an Object that encapsulates the path of a document. You cannot "auto-magically" get the values of the referred doc when querying the parent doc, you need to issue a new query. VueFire may indeed resolves it but so far, afaik, there is no near future plan to have that in the "standard" SDKs.

Comment: Wouldn't you agree, that automagic ressolving by VueFire is advantageous at least to some extent? I believe that does not work with paths encoded as strings.

Comment: @Boern Yes I agree that this would be an interesting feature, without any doubt! I just answered that I didn't heard of any plan to implement such feature in a near future :-) Now, about VueFire, I have to say that I don't use it in my Vue.js apps because I think it has quite some limitations. I prefer to have the full power of the JS SDK and the time I could save by using VueFire doesn't really worth loosing the JS SDK flexibility. (that's only my opinion, of course...)