# State immutability not satisfied during populating the state in NgRx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an an array of objects, which is downloaded from the backend, which now I want to to use to populate my state variable. The problem is that the object has multiple levels of nesting.

The state is  -

```
const initialState: SummaryStateInterface = {
  summaryList: [], // Problem is only with this one. 
  editIndex: null,
  editItem: null,
  addingNew: false,
  modifications: false,
  isLoading: false,
}
```

the SummaryStateInterface is this:

```
export interface SummaryStateInterface {
  summaryList: Summary[] | null;
  editIndex: number | null;
  editItem: Summary | null;
  addingNew: boolean | null;
  modifications: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean;
}
```

The Summary model is this:

```
export class Summary {
  @required()
  title: string;
  @required()    // these decorators are for form validation  
  text: string;
  @required()    // these decorators are for form validation
  focus: Focus[] = [];
  @prop()
  focusRef: DocumentReference[];
  seqNo: number;
  id: string;
}
```

the Focus model is this -

```
export class Focus {
  @required()
  name: string;
  seqNo: number;
  id: string;
}
```

The effect that passes data to this action is -

```
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(readSummaryAction),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.service.list$.pipe(
          map(list => {
            console.log('This is the list ', list);
            return readSummarySuccessAction({ list });
          }),
          catchError(() => of(readSummaryFailureAction())),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

The reducer there I am trying to populate summaryList is like this -

```
  on(
    readSummarySuccessAction,
    (state, action): SummaryStateInterface => {
      const updatedSummaryList = [...state.summaryList].concat(
        JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(action.list)),
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        summaryList: updatedSummaryList,
        ),
      };
    },
  ),
```

The data passed for this action an array of 2 items
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {title: "Resume", url: "resume", ionicIcon: "", customIcon: "./assets/portfolio.svg", open: false, …}
1: {title: "Database", url: "", ionicIcon: "", customIcon: "./assets/server.svg", open: false, …}
length: 2
**proto**: Array(0)

One of these items is -

```
focus: Array(3)
0: {id: "focusId1", name: "Main", seqNo: 1}
1: {id: "focusId2", name: "CFD", seqNo: 2}
2: {id: "focusId3", seqNo: 4.5, name: "Web"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
focusRef: (3) [n, n, n] // Firebase document reference
id: "sum1"
seqNo: 2.5
text: "Versatile and detail-driven Mechanical Engineer with a wealth of experience and knowledge in the Thermal-Fluids area. "
title: "Professional Summary"
```

the error thrown are -

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot freeze
    at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103583:12)
    at http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103603:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103586:40)
    at http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103603:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103586:40)
    at http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103603:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

UnsubscriptionErrorImpl {message: "2 errors occurred during unsubscription:↵1) TypeEr…: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible", name: "UnsubscriptionError", errors: Array(2)}

core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '__zone_symbol__state' of object '[object Object]'

zone-evergreen.js:976 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible

**Is it possible to get some feedback ?**
I am willing to restructure (flatten) the state - but to what and how, I don't know.

Comment: Looks like `focus` or `focusRef` in `Summary` are being modified causing the cannot freeze error.. Do you need those properties in your frontend?

Comment: Yes i do need them for front end. Focus ref was a firebase document reference which had circular references. I suspect that to cause problems. So i am changing that to a string variable now

Answer (score 0):

The focusRef property in the Summary class was a DocumentReference. Unfortunately for whatever reasons, DocumentReference field in Firebase has circular references.

The circular reference topic is discussed in this post :
[Firestore references create a "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410448/firestore-references-create-a-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

I converted these references (ref) to strings - using their path property (ref.path).

Once strings all these errors went away. I would welcome if someone could explain how freeze from core.js would work - It was throwing following error -

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot freeze
    at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103583:12)
    at http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103603:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103586:40)
    at http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103603:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at freeze (http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103586:40)
    at http://localhost:8101/vendor.js:103603:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

**Unrelated but useful**
To detect circular references in an object (x) is: Do
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)). This expression will fail.